# remove function deletes wrong items from array

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays, indexing

So i am making my to-do app and i have encountered this weird problem where my removeToDo function targets wrong items in weird pattern apart from the very first deleted item(which always is being removed just fine). Let's say we have items in the array with id's from 0 to 6 :

```
Clicked to remove item with ID = 3 - removed item with ID = 3
Clicked to remove item with ID = 4 - removed item with ID = 5
Clicked to remove item with ID = 5 - removed item with ID = 6
Clicked to remove item with ID = 0 - removed item with ID = 0
Clicked to remove item with ID = 2 - removed item with ID = 4
Clicked to remove item with ID = 1 - removed item with ID = 2
Clicked to remove item with ID = 6 - removed item with ID = 1
```

So it's not really following an obvious pattern (thought it may be something like id + 1 or something but it doesn't seem like it). Also i did exactly the same test as above for the second time to see if it randomizes, it doesn't, the results were exactly the same.

Here is some code
HTML

```
<body>
    <div class='app'>

        <ul id='list'>

        </ul>
        <div class="footer">
            <i class="fas fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true" id='addButton'></i>
            <input type="text" id='itemInput' placeholder="Add a to-do" />
        </div>
    </div>
<script src="./app.js"></script>

</body>
```

JS

```
const list = document.getElementById("list");
const input = document.getElementById("itemInput");

let id;

//get the item from the local storage
let data = localStorage.getItem('TODO');

//check if data is not empty
if(data) {
    LIST = JSON.parse(data)
    id = LIST.length; // set the list id to the last in the array
    loadList(LIST); // load all the items in the array to the UI 
} else {
    //if data is empty
    LIST = [];
    id = 0;
}

function loadList(array) {
    array.forEach(item => {
        addToDo(item.name, item.id, item.done, item.trash);
    })
}

function addToDo(toDo, id, done, trash) {

    // if trash is true do not execute the code below
    if (trash) {return ;}
    const DONE = done ? check : uncheck;
    const LINE = done ? lineThrough : "";

    const text =`
    <li class="item">
        <i class="far ${DONE}" id='${id}'></i>
            <div class="description ${LINE} wrap">${toDo}</div>
        <i class="fas fa-trash-alt" id='${id}'></i>
    </li>`;
    const position = "beforeend";
    list.insertAdjacentHTML(position, text);        
}

// remove to-do
function removeToDo(element, i) {
    let newList = [...LIST]
    element.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(element.parentNode);
    i = newList.indexOf(newList[event.target.id]) //<-- i think that is the problem, the indexing is not working as it should, as a result app gets confused ?
    alert(i)
    //newList[event.target.id].trash = true;  
    newList.splice(i, 1);
    LIST = newList;
    console.log(LIST);
    return LIST;

}

// click listener for job complete and job delete
list.addEventListener('click', e => {
    const element = e.target;
    if(e.target.className == "fas fa-trash-alt" ){
        removeToDo(element);
    }else if(e.target.className == "far fa-circle") {
        jobComplete(element);
    }else if(e.target.className == "far fa-check-circle"){
        jobComplete(element);
    }
    }
)

//add a task with "enter" key
document.addEventListener("keyup", (event) => {
    if(event.keyCode == 13){
        const toDo = input.value;
            if(toDo) {
                addToDo(toDo, id, false, false);
                LIST.push(
                    {
                        name: toDo,
                        id: id,
                        done: false,
                        trash: false
                    }
                );
                localStorage.setItem('TODO', JSON.stringify(LIST));
                id++;
                input.value = '';
            }
        }
})
```

EDIT :
The items deleted in weird pattern are in the LIST array, actual buttons i click are being deleted just fine. I think i didn't explained that well enough

Comment: Instead of `element.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(element.parentNode);`, just use `element.remove()` when you have the correct element that should be taken out.

Comment: It just deletes the bin icon, that's why it was there.
`element.parentNode.remove();` works for removing it but the original problem still persists.

Comment: Please show an example of the `localStorage` string that you would be getting.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Storage TODO: 
"[{"name":"1","id":0,"done":false,"trash":false},
{"name":"2","id":1,"done":false,"trash":false},
{"name":"3","id":2,"done":false,"trash":false},
{"name":"4","id":3,"done":false,"trash":false},
{"name":"5","id":4,"done":false,"trash":false},
{"name":"6","id":5,"done":false,"trash":false},
{"name":"7","id":6,"done":false,"trash":false},
{"name":"8","id":7,"done":false,"trash":false}]"
length: 1__proto__: Storage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it will be best not to consider the id for removing items.
You can consider the value as well.
Instead of splice(i,1), please try using

```
newList = newList.filter(function( obj ) {
  return obj.name !== element.previousElementSibling.innerHTML;
});
```

Comment: Ok so that seems to be working so far, but could you explain that method to me please ? I would like to understand what it's doing there and actually learn something :) And another question the ID is still being a problem there as whenever i delete something, the console.log shows up right id's for only few first removals, then it just goes to -1 on everything ? Also if i delete something and then add new to-do, it gets the id of -1 ?

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer. So,after splicing the array for once,it doesn't have the same ids as the element in the DOM(inspect element and check).The id that is passed in the function is the id of the element but the array indices for the elements have changed after splicing an item.So i have taken the html of the previous sibling of the bin icon i.e. the div just above the icon and used array filter method (compared the text to the name property of the obj which is same on your case) to filter out the rest of the element except for the one deleted and assigned it to the original array

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this:

```
 id = LIST.length; // set the list id to the last in the array
```

The `.length` property of an array returns the number of items in the array, but array indexes are zero-based. An array with 5 items in it (`length === 5`), will have its last item index be `4`.

The index of the last item in an array is `.length -1`.

Comment: I tried it, unfortunately it did not solve the problem :(

Comment: @PawelKrzesinski It still is a problem and should be corrected.